# How to find nearest value using queryDSL JPA

Tags: spring-data, querydsl

I want to rewrite the following SQL using QueryDSL JPA and Spring Data `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`:

```
select * from RoadObject order by abs(positionM - 1000)
```

I've tried this:

```
Predicate predicate = RoadObjectPredicates.toPredicate(filter); // some condition...
QRoadObject obj = QRoadObject.roadObject;
OrderSpecifier order = new OrderSpecifier<>(Order.ASC, obj.positionM.subtract(1000).abs());
Iterable<RoadObject> test = roadObjectDao.findAll(predicate, order);
```

But it throws:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysema.query.types.expr.NumberOperation cannot be cast to com.mysema.query.types.Path
```

**EDIT** The full stacktrace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysema.query.types.expr.NumberOperation cannot be cast to com.mysema.query.types.Path
at org.springframework.data.querydsl.QSort.toOrder(QSort.java:89) ~[spring-data-commons-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.querydsl.QSort.toOrders(QSort.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.querydsl.QSort.<init>(QSort.java:55) ~[spring-data-commons-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.querydsl.QSort.<init>(QSort.java:46) ~[spring-data-commons-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.findAll(QueryDslJpaRepository.java:105) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.findAll(QueryDslJpaRepository.java:44) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:343) ~[spring-data-commons-1.7.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at ru.rosavtodor.sc.monitoring.web.services.RegistryListService.listRoadObjects_aroundBody4(RegistryListService.java:119) ~[RegistryListService.class:na]
at ru.rosavtodor.sc.monitoring.web.services.RegistryListService$AjcClosure5.run(RegistryListService.java:1) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59) ~[spring-aspects-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65) ~[spring-aspects-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63) ~[spring-aspects-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at ru.rosavtodor.sc.monitoring.web.services.RegistryListService.listRoadObjects(RegistryListService.java:112) ~[RegistryListService.class:na]
at ru.rosavtodor.sc.monitoring.web.services.RegistryListService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$db93970e.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644) ~[spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at ru.rosavtodor.sc.monitoring.web.services.RegistryListService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$764e1c0b.listRoadObjects(<generated>) ~[spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
at ru.rosavtodor.sc.monitoring.web.controllers.RegistryController.getRoadObjects(RegistryController.java:93) ~[RegistryController.class:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215) ~[spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) ~[spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870) ~[spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.53]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_51]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [na:1.7.0_51]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Could you provide the full stacktrace?

Comment: I've posted the full stacktrace, could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed in Spring Data Dijkstra SR4.

Bugs [DATACMNS-566](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-566) and [DATAJPA-596](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-596)

EDIT: I modified my answer to really be an answer!

Comment: "Spring Data Dijkstra SR4" - what does it mean? There are very strange versions in their jira "1.6.4 (Dijkstra SR4)", "1.7 GA (Evans)". How do they correlate with spring-data-jpa versions?